# How to get Maven to see additional Kotlin source folder generated by JOOQ?

Tags: maven, kotlin, jooq

I am using Jooq's Kotlin source generator to generate additional Kotlin code in `${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/jooq`.

I added the following Maven config to get it to see the additonal source directory:

```xml
<build>
        <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/kotlin</sourceDirectory>
        <testSourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/test/kotlin</testSourceDirectory>
          <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <args>
                        <arg>-Xjsr305=strict</arg>
                    </args>
                    <compilerPlugins>
                        <plugin>spring</plugin>
                    </compilerPlugins>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                        <artifactId>kotlin-maven-allopen</artifactId>
                        <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>compile</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sourceDirs>
                                <sourceDir>${project.basedir}/src/main/kotlin</sourceDir>
                                <sourceDir>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/jooq</sourceDir>
                            </sourceDirs>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>test-compile</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test-compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sourceDirs>
                                <sourceDir>${project.basedir}/src/test/kotlin</sourceDir>
                            </sourceDirs>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
</build>
```

However when i try to compile, it seems Kotlin compiler still is unaware of the sources in the `${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/jooq` directory. What am i missing?

Comment: Just to be sure, your `${project.build.directory}` *does* point to the correct location, e.g. `${project.basedir}/target`? For reference, the jOOQ MCVE template has a functional `pom.xml` configuration. It looks like yours, but perhaps, you can use it to find the subtle difference between the builds: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ-mcve